# Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: jsf

I want to create a project with primefaces, I made a simple example of hello world, but I can not deploy the war that I'm building, I did it with eclipse and weblogic, when placed in the server I get the following error:

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

What am I doing wrong? new i'm sorry if it's something very basic.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Hello to everybody i found the answer !!!

http://wiki.flexive.org/confluence/display/FX/Deploy+in+WebLogic+10.3

maybe can help to somebody!!!!